# Есть задача по t-sql, как правильнее вывести дату перехода по условию на ms sql 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Исходная таблица]

Исходная таблица. Где поле докид-идентификатор документа,st статус документа,date - дата перехода на статус.

### Необходимо написать запрос к таблице, который выведет: 1.Идентификатор документа 2.Статус 3.Дата перехода на данный статус 4.Дата перехода на следующий статус если перехода не было, то отобразить тек дату

Имеется ввиду если docid ранее имел какой то статус то писать дату перехода на статус , если нет то текущую дату

Comment: Посетители, просматривая заголовки, ищут решение своей проблемы... Что можно найти по такому названию, как у Вас? Какая задача? Зашли за помощью - так и другим не отказывайте в помощи.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду отсортировать по  Date, и в последнем (4) столбце выводить  Date из следующей строки если в следующей строке St такой же как в текущей?

Comment: Имеется ввиду если docid ранее имел какой то статус то писать дату перехода на статус , если нет то текущую дату

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с нумерацией и самоджойном для 2008й версии

исходные:

```
declare @t table (docId int, st varchar(1), d date);

insert into @t values
    (1, 'c', '2014-02-28'),
    (1, 'c', '2014-01-13'),
    (1, 'a', '2014-01-22'),
    (2, 'b', '2014-05-02'),
    (3, 'd', '2014-02-24');
```

запрос

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT docId, st, d
         , row_number() over (partition by docId order by d) as rn
    FROM @t
)
SELECT d1.docId, d1.st, d1.d
    , COALESCE(d2.d, cast(getDate() as DATE)) as nextDate
FROM data AS d1
LEFT JOIN data AS d2 ON (
        d2.docId = d1.docId 
        AND d2.rn = d1.rn + 1
    )
```

либо через подзапрос

Comment: Всегда будет выводиться дата перехода на первый статус

Comment: @ГерманБорисов c с чего вдруг?

Comment: @teran благодарю

Comment: Извиняюсь, невнимательно посмотрел.

Comment: А что будет работать быстрее, join ? Если сравнивать с под запросом @teran@ГерманБорисов

Comment: @JUMALA если объем данных не большой, то разницы не увидите. А на больших объемах нужно взять да проверить оба варианта. и про индексы не забыть.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT docid, 
       st, 
       date, 
       COALESCE(LEAD(date) OVER (PARTITION BY docid ORDER BY date), now()) nextdate
FROM source_table
```

Comment: работать будет только с 2012й версии

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis Если автор не указал версию, то вполне можно давать решение хоть для самой распоследней... или решение его устроит, или он одумается и уточнит среду исполнения. А рисовать решение, непременно совместимое с SQL7 - как-то некомильфо...

Comment: Одумался , приношу свои извинения.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.docid, 
       A.st, 
       A.date, 
       COALESCE((SELECT MIN(B.date) FROM source_table B WHERE B.docid=A.docid AND B.date>A.date), now()) nextdate
FROM source_table A
```